# Make4ht and enumerate

Tags: enumerate, tex4ht, make4ht

The enumerate package causes problems with make4ht, there are extra spaces and strange alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item text
    \item other text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I compile with `make4ht file.tex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a large space between the enumerate label and text. You can remove it using the following config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{dd.enumerate{margin-left:0;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It uses a CSS code that sets the left margin of enumerate text to zero, which removes the large space.

This is the result:

[image]